# jQuery Mobile Multi-Select from asynchronous data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile

I have a little problem with jQuery Mobile and AngularJS.

I want a multi-select so the user can chose a category. Categories have parents and childs. The whole structure comes from a database so its an asynchronous call to get the data.

The problem is that the select element has the data but doesn't show it unless you click on the first empty option.

Maybe i'll better show than tell

http://plnkr.co/edit/7UwGjSRfGEnhIvSrtGjV

```
<div ng-show="catsready" id="jqselect">
  <label for="multiselect" class="select">Multi-select:</label>
  <select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="left">
    <option>Choose a few options:</option>
    <optgroup ng-repeat="parent in cats" label="{{parent.name}}">
      <option ng-repeat="child in parent.childs" value="" jq-select>{{child.name}}</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After angular has added/changed the optiongroups and options, you need to tell jQM to refresh the selectmenu widget:

```
$("#multiselect").selectmenu("refresh", true);
```

API Doc: http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh